# Raster field after Join is just black

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I have a polygon Feature Class and a Table with a raster field. They have a N : 1 relation.

I have joined the Table to the Feature Class. After this, if I open a Pop Up of a Feature inside my Feature Class, I am only seeing a black rectangle instead of the raster.

[image]

With a selection on the Table and then under Map -> Selection -> Attributes I can see the Raster just fine. With the Feature Class I can only see a black rectangle.

Is there a possible solution without saving my diagrams outside of my GDB and using paths?

ArcGIS Pro Version: 2.8.2

Comment: Please add a screen shot to show what you mean by black rectangle?

Comment: I added a shot of the PopUp.